# How to pass value to the JQUery call back method?

Tags: jquery, css

I came across the below example for setting css style to a div tag. my doubt is,  what value does the '**index**'value in the funtion param holds. or if the user hass to pass **index** value, then how to pass the value(ie usage) for **index** param for callback function  ?

```
$( "div.example" ).css( "width", function( index ) {return index * 50;});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

index is the index of the element in all elements. You should not pass the value for that.

Suppose if you have 3 elements with class `example` in div, index of 1st element will be 0 and its width will be set to `0px (0*50)`. Index of 2nd element will be 1 and its width will be set to `50px (1*50)`, index of 3rd element will be 2 and its width will be set to `100px (2*50)`

Answer (score 0):

index value starts from zero in callback function and it is incremented by 1(default).

If you want to initialize or set a specific value to it yo have to do it in this way :

```
        $("div").css('width', function(i) {
            i = 5;
            return (i * 50);
        });
```

But here the value of index is always set to 5 for selected element. So, i suggest you to use default functioning of index value in this way.

```
        $("div").css('width', function(i) {
            ++i;     // or i++;
            return (i * 50);
        });
```

Here, I have incremented index i just to skip zero value.

OR

if you want to set some start value to index then see the following code snippet:

```
    let j = 5;
    $("div").css('width', function(i) {
        i = inc();
        function inc() {
            j++;
            return j; 
        };
        return (i * 50);
    });
```

Hope now you might get expected output. :):)